# Deep Learning With TensorFlow and Cifar10

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

> I can't figure out how to make my code working. And i'm looking for help :)
> And i'm working with cifar10 images classification.Using Tensorflow 1.x version
> Line 40 is sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x : x_train , y_ : y_train})

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10, mnist
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,3072])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[10])
# Data normalization
x_train = x_train/255
y_train = y_train/255
# four hidden layers
(hidden1_size,hidden2_size,hidden3_size,hidden4_size) = (100,100,100,100)
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3072,hidden1_size],stddev=0.1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[hidden1_size]))
z1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,W1)+b1)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden1_size,hidden2_size],stddev=0.1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[hidden2_size]))
z2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(z1,W2)+b2)
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden2_size,hidden3_size],stddev=0.1))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[hidden3_size]))
z3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(z2,W3)+b3)
W4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden3_size,hidden4_size],stddev=0.1))
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[hidden4_size]))
z4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(z3,W4)+b4)
W5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden4_size,10],stddev=0.1))
b5 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(z4,W5)+b5)
# this is a cross entropy
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y)))
# let's train to get the minimum loss using back+forward propagation
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range (100):
        sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x : x_train , y_ : y_train})
```

> my output is File "C:/Users/איימן/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/aiman.py", line 40, in 
> sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x : x_train , y_ : y_train})
> File "C:\Users\איימן\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 956, in run
> run_metadata_ptr)
> File "C:\Users\איימן\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1156, in _run
> (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50000, 32, 32, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 3072)'

Comment: Better to switch to TF2.

Comment: But our lecturer doesn't want too :( , And i can't figure out how to fix the code.

Comment: Seems you forgot to flatten/reshape the training set so the shape should be (50000, 3072)

Comment: Thanks that worked i got this now: y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])
and the error is :ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50000, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'
what i can do?  Thanks alot!!

Comment: I changed this lines in my code : y_train = y_train.reshape((5000 , 10))
y_= tf.reshape(y_,shape=[5000,10]) ,but it still doesn't work ,the reason is : tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [?,10]
  [[{{node Placeholder_1}}]]